# Select p tag, but exclude some children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jquery to select a section of copy:

```
str = '.main-content p:nth-child('+num+')';
string = jQuery(str).html();
```

(num is declared elsewhere and is not an issue).

This selects all content within the p tag (obviously), however the p tags that I am selecting have nested a tags and strong tags.
Is there a way of selecting the p tag and excluding the strong tag for example. I have tried the below code:

```
str = '.main-content p:nth-child('+num+') :not(strong)';
```

But this selects all the children elements (excluding strong) but not the content of the actual p tag.

Any ideas would be welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Edit - Example requested:

```
<p><strong>Content that I want to ignore</strong> This is some content which I would like to include. <a href="#">also keep this</a></p>
```

Preferably return this:

```
<p>This is some content which I would like to include. <a href="#">also keep this</a></p>
```

or this:

```
This is some content which I would like to include. <a href="#">also keep this</a>
```

Comment: Can you show example HTML and desired output please?

Comment: Add a class to the elements you want to modify.

Comment: Can you be more specific? How would this help exactly? Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var p = $('.main-content p:nth-child('+num+')').clone();
p.find('*:not(a)').remove();
var your_string = p.html();
```

or you can specify exact tags to remove:

```
p.find('strong, b, i').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```js
var str = $('p').html();
str = str.replace(/<strong>[^<]*<\/strong>/gi,'');
console.log(str.trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><strong>Content that I want to ignore</strong> This is some content which I would like to include. <a href="#">also keep this</a></p>
```